# Plugin in Magento 2.1 not being recognized

Tags: magento-2.1, plugin

I'm trying to create a plugin for Magento 2.1.3 that disables the flat rate shipping method in the cart, but keeps it enabled in the admin panel.

I've followed the instructions to the best of my knowledge, and Magento doesn't seem to be picking up my plugin.

Here's what I've got:

app/code/MaadDecor/DisableFlatRate/etc/di.xml:

```
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
<type name="Magento\OfflineShipping\Model\Carrier\Flatrate">
    <plugin name="hidePlug" type="MaadDecor\DisableFlatRate\Plugin\Hide" sortOrder="1" disabled="false"/>
</type>
```

app/code/MaadDecor/DisableFlatRate/Plugin/Hide.php

```
<?php

namespace MaadDecor\DisableFlatRate\Plugin;

use Magento\Backend\Model\Auth\Session;
use Psr\Log\LoggerInterface;

class Hide
{
    protected $backendSession;

    /**
    * @var LoggerInterface
    */

    private $logger;

    public function __construct(Session $session, LoggerInterface $logger)
    {
        $this->backendSession = $session;
        $this->logger = $logger;
    }

    public function aroundCollectRates($subject, callable $proceed)
    {

        $this->logger->info('hit before the auth check');
        if ($this->backendSession->isLoggedIn()) {
            return $proceed();
        }
        $this->logger->info('hit after the auth check');
        //        return $proceed();
        return false;
    }    
}
```

For some reason none of the logs are being added, and the shipping rate still displays on the front end.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

you need to move your di.xml from

```
app/code/MaadDecor/DisableFlatRate/etc/di.xml
```

to

```
app/code/MaadDecor/DisableFlatRate/di.xml
```

Now clean cache and then try.

Comment: That didn't do anything, and I see in all the other packages that their di.xml is in the etc subfolder.

Comment: have you try caching and then check.

Answer (score 0):

Replace the **aroundCollectRates** Function with this :

```
public function aroundCollectRates(
    Magento\OfflineShipping\Model\Carrier\Flatrate $subject,
    \Closure $proceed
) {
    $this->logger->info('hit before the auth check');
    if ($this->backendSession->isLoggedIn()) {
        return $proceed();
    }
    $this->logger->info('hit after the auth check');
    //        return $proceed();
    return false;
}
```

Please reply if this solves your problem.

Comment: This doesn't make a difference.  I just dont think this method is being called somehow.

Comment: Well this is one of the obsolete_classes in Magento 2, That might be the reason Or It the flatrate method is disabled from admin.